# Composed components not working in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a **MySVG** react component which has another composed component inside called **svgbox**. I can't see svgbox rendering. If I use the svg to draw the rectangle (currently in the svgbox) in the MySVG directly, it works.

What change I have to make the composed **svgbox** to work?

**mysvg.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import svgBox from 'svgbox'

export default class MySVG extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row"> 
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <svg width="700" height="500">
                        <svgBox/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**svgbox.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export default class svgBox extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <g transform="translate(50, 20)"> 
                <rect width="100" height="200" styles="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
            </g>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you move the svg element currently in your MySVG component into the svg box component does it render?

Comment: Have you inspected via dev tools? What do you see when you navigate to `svg` element above, do you see any children inside it?

Comment: (a) If I move the **svg** element to **svgbox**, I don't see anything. I think the **render** method in the **svgbox** is not called, however I see the same component's constructor is being called during the rendering of the whole page. (b) When I check the dev tools, there is no children elements that I see inside the **svg** element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 posible problems here. You must capitalize the component. Use ./ in import from. Use a space before the closing />.

```
    import React from 'react'
    //import svgBox from 'svgbox'
    import SvgBox from './svgbox'

    export default class MySVG extends React.Component {
            constructor () {
                    super();
            }

            render() {
                    return (
                            <div className="row"> 
                                    <div className="col-md-12">
                                            <svg width="700" height="500">
                                                    //<svgBox/>
                                                    <SvgBox />
                                            </svg>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    );
            }
    }
```

Comment: The react requires the components to start with capitulation. Does not need the path or the space.

Comment: I removed the ./ from import and got this.

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Cannot find module 'dnd.ctrl' from 'K:\Projects\ReactPatterns\React.13\DragAndDrop\ui-src\components'
    at K:\Projects\ReactPatterns\React.13\DragAndDrop\node_modules\

Comment: I set up the ES6 modules (export and import) through JSPM module manager. The JSPM adds a map to **package.json** which will pull the right module from the jspm_packages folder. It may be working fine without the ./ in my case as a result of this.

Comment: Your right that it is a tool chain issue. Browserify/babel want the path. You were also correct about the space. I remembered getting an error because of the space at some time though.

Answer (score 0):

Is your component properly exported/imported ?

Comment: If move the whole **<g>** to MySVG component, it works and I can see a rectangle. The **styles** is what the react expects.

Comment: have you exported your module properly ? and imported properly ? what's in svgbox when you import it ?